# Making codes obscure

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-widget

There are several tools that can easily reverse engineer the app and shows all the classes and resources easily.My question is what are the ways to make the code obscure.My code is unique and i do not want anyone to reverse engineer it.I want to know Preventive ways.

Comment: Have you taken a look at [ProGuard](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html)?

Comment: @Rajesh I reverse engineered a very famous app just to check the level of obfuscation.It wasn't too difficult to understand the code.I assume they must be using progaurd.Is there any other way too?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531187/android-and-obfuscation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of free obfuscators besides proGuard, but most apps will use proGuard cause  it's recommended & supported by google.

So everything you need to know: (about proguard and beyond)

http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2010/09/proguard-android-and-licensing-server.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:+blogspot/hsDu+(Android+Developers+Blog)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531187/android-and-obfuscation

Comment: BTW does ProGuard also hides my database?It's an important resource to me.I have bundled it with the app.

Answer (score 2):

> My question is what are the ways to make the code obscure

Nothing will give you significant improvement over ProGuard without seriously impacting runtime performance.

> My code is unique and i do not want anyone to reverse engineer it.

Then do not put that code on somebody else's machine. Keep it on your server.

> does ProGuard also hides my database?

No.

> It's an important resource to me.

If by "an important resource" you mean "my database is unique and i do not want anyone to read it", then do not put the database on somebody else's machine. Keep it on your server.

Anything that goes on a user's device -- code or data -- is accessible by that user with sufficient work.

Comment: Thanks for the well explained answer.